# Dokku - Persistant storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

What is the best method to setup persistant storage for a Rails/Dokku app?  The Dokku docs dont seem to say anything about the subject.  When used Google to search the docs site the only thing it returned was the [dokku-volume-plugin](https://github.com/ohardy/dokku-volume), which I've tried the  without success.

I can create a volume for my app:

```
dokku volume:add myapp /public
```

but nothing gets written to the volume.

Is this the current(2015) best way to setup persistant storage with Dokku?  If it is, am I missing something?

Comment: See @mixxorzs answer, and I think it should be /app/public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the archives, so that nobody walks down the wrong path:

The current (`2016, dokku > 0.5`) path changed. I used @mixxorz approach in the past with success, but as of now the built-in plugin `storage` seems to take over the stage:

`(... ssh dokku@host || dokku ...) storage:mount <app> /var/lib/dokku/data/storage:/app/public/uploads`

Its well documented at http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/dokku-storage/ .

The concepts stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

I use [dokku-volume-plugin](https://github.com/ohardy/dokku-volume) without any problems. Here's how it works.

The `dokku volumes:add myapp /app/uploads/` command adds a volume that will be persisted on the host for the files stored inside your app's `/app/uploads/` directory. If your app tries to write into that directory, it would instead by written on the host. The files are actually stored in the folder `/home/dokku/.o_volume/`.

From what I can tell, the only difference with your command and my command is the trailing slash. `dokku volume:add myapp /public/` should fix your issues.

Alternatively, you could try an [Amazon S3 based solution](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1K43Z7KXHM5D5/Uploading-Files-to-Amazon-S3).

Comment: Your explanation should be the explanation in the documentation. Thanks.